# Need 3 divs in a row with the center div filling the width of the page, regardless of content length

Tags: html, css, webkit, css-tables

I am trying to create an html interface, where rows will be dynamically added to my web page.

The way I am currently doing it is by using nested DIVs with the CSS display style set to table.

Each row has 3 divs. The left div and the right div have a fixed width, while the middle div should expand to fit the page horizontally regardless of the length of it's content.

My problem is I'm not sure how to make that center div expand the entire remaining width of the page. With the code below, the center div is as small as the content.

I tried a solution that floated the left div left, and the right div right, however that would not let me select a row of text properly. i.e., if I started selecting the right div's content, then dragged towards the left, the left and center div would not be selected.

The solution only needs to target webkit based engines, as my code will only be used in a webkit based environment.

EDIT!

I forgot to mention that I also tried using tables. However I also need to avoid getting horizontal scroll bars appearing on the page when the screen is shrinking. When I use tables and shrink the page, the center div stops shrinking at a certain point (due to the fixed width percentages I guess).

My CSS code:

```
.chatarea
{
    display: table;
    height = 100%;
    padding-top:50px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.row
{
    #display: table-row;
}

.nick
{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 140px;
    border-style: solid;
    text-align: right;
}

.timestamp
{
    display: table-cell;
    width 50px;
    border-style: solid;
}

.message
{
    display: table-cell;
    border-style: solid;
}
```

And the relevant html

```
<div class="chatarea">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="nick">
            <p>Some Nick</p>
        </div>
        <div class="message">
            <p>Some Message</p>
        </div>
        <div class="timestamp">
            <p>Some Timestamp</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is a solution:

- Add `border-collapse: collapse;` to .chartarea to remove the double border width.
- Add `width: 100%` to .chartarea to cover the entire width of the window.
- Add `width: 80%;` to .message to have it grow as the window width changes.
- Add `white-space: nowrap;` to .nick to control wrapping.
- Add `white-space: nowrap;` to .timestamp to control wrapping.
- Uncomment `display: table-row` in .row

Check out this <strike>fiddle</strike>.
**Note:** the fiddle page appears to have been removed by the server.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. This is exactly what I have been looking for! I made a few adjustments along the way, but the key ideas you have mentioned are used. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `display` styles. Then just use:

```
.nick {
    width: 50px;
    float: left;
}
.timestamp {
    width: 50px;
    float: right;
}
```

Then `.message` will take up the remaining width.

Alternatively, just use a `<table>` element.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for a suggestion. However, I tried this solution already.

You cannot select the entire row of text with this solution. As i mentioned in my original post, if you float the nick and time stamp div, you can't reliably select a row of text.

I forgot to mention in my original post that If i use tables, and I shrink the window, I will get horizontal scroll bars. I wish to avoid that.

Comment: Oh yeah, missed that part >_> I'm not sure I understand your problem with scrollbars appearing... That doesn't happen to me. How are you setting the width of the table, for that to happen?

Comment: When I add a table row, I set each of the 3 table cells to have a width in %. So the first table-cell has a width of 10%, the center cell has a width of 80% and the last cell has a width of 10%.

The horizontal scroll bars appear when the center div has multiple lines of text. Ie, the content cant fit on one line.

Comment: Can you show an example of this? I've never had this problem before.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't do it fake it. Just put your `.nick` and `.timestamp` inside `.message` and position them absolutely.

```
.nick
{
    width: 140px;
    border-right-style: solid;
    text-align: right;
    height:100%; 
    position:absolute; 
    top:0; 
    left:0;
}

.timestamp
{
    width: 50px;
    border-left-style: solid;
    position:absolute; 
    top:0; 
    right:0; 
    height:100%;
}

.message
{
    border-style: solid;
    padding:0 50px 0 140px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}
```

I've check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qFqT8/2/) in recent chrome and safari (on windows) and had no problems with selecting text.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your suggestion. It works quite well! However I still prefer to keep the nick/time stamp separate.